# Can I use two 5K and one 4K LG UltraFine displays simultaneously with a 2019 15" MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, display

[MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2019) - Technical Specifications](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP794) page says the following about video support:

> Simultaneously supports full native resolution on the built-in display at millions of colors and:
>
> - Up to two displays with 5120-by-2880 resolution at 60Hz at over a billion colors
> - Up to four displays with 4096-by-2304 resolution at 60Hz at over a billion colors

i.e., two 5K or four 4K displays.

My question is, can it drive two 5K and one 4K LG UltraFine displays simultaneously and work well?